# worker thread is not notified in multithread code

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to write a traditional producer and consumer multithread program in Java. Producer thread will send message to thread-safe List until this list get full. once buffer is full, it will notify worker thread and buffer will be cleared. In my coding, the worker thread is not notified.

Do you know the reason ? Thanks.

```
package com;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class ThreadTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final List<String> bufferSafeList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());

        final ReentrantLock bufferLock = new ReentrantLock();
        final Condition bufferFull = bufferLock.newCondition();
      //  final Condition bufferEmpty = bufferLock.newCondition();

        Thread producerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        bufferLock.lock();
                        bufferSafeList.add(System.currentTimeMillis() + "");
                        System.out.println("add to buffer " + bufferSafeList.size());
                        if (bufferSafeList.size() > 100) {
                            System.out.println("send wake up signal");
                            bufferFull.signalAll();

                            //waiting for buff cleared
                            while(!bufferSafeList.isEmpty()){
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                            }                           
                        }

                         Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    finally {
                        bufferLock.unlock();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        producerThread.start();

        Thread workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        bufferLock.lock();
                        System.out.println("waiting for wakeup signal");
                        bufferFull.await();
                        System.out.println("clear buffer");

                        bufferSafeList.clear();                      
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        bufferLock.unlock();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        workerThread.start();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only `unlock` the `bufferLock` in the finally, so the `workerThread` will never be able to progress further than trying to obtain the `lock`

When the buffer is full `unlock` so that the `workerThread` can continue

Comment: I put unlock directly after bufferFull.signalAll(); still doesn't work.

Comment: You will need to `unlock` before signalling

Answer (score 0):

If the producer thread happens to run first, as it is likely to do because it is started first, it will likely lock `bufferLock` first, in which case it will fill the list and invoke `bufferFull.signalAll()` while the consumer is still waiting to acquire the lock.  You then busy-wait for the worker to clear the list, which it never will do because it cannot proceed.

Moreover, even if you unlocked the lock after signalling, that would be too late.  By the time the worker is `await()`ing the condition, the signal has already come and gone.  Indeed, there is a race condition there even if the producer waits to acquire the lock until it is ready to signal.

The correct usage of a condition variable always involves *testing* whether the expected condition is satisfied before waiting, and looping back to wait some more if it is not satisfied after resuming from the wait.  You can overcome the race in your code by implementing this.

Comment: do you have a link of correct usage of a condition variable ?

Comment: @EdwardChen, How about in the description section of [the API docs for java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html)?  Or this quite parallel to the usual pattern for use of the lower-level `wait()`/`notify()` methods provided by all `Object`s, and you can surely find multiple tutorials on that without assistance.  And this is not strictly a Java thing either.  [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+use+a+condition+variable) seems very informative about the subject.